# Elasticsearch v-1.5 showing high CPU & memory utilization

Tags: elasticsearch

We've recently started using elasticsearch(V-1.5) on one of our app & started facing following issues..

- Generating Logs ( Exceptionally very high viz.. 5 min 5GB log )
- High CPU Utilization
- In-spite of deleting logs, disk space was not released. Needed Hard 
  boot the server to release the logs space.

**System Configuration**

- OS - Linux 14.04 LTS 64bit Ubuntu.
- vCPU - 2 Core
- vRAM - 8 GB
- Disk Space - 100 GB

Don't know what's going wrong. Any clue...

### Elastic search error log

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post ap
i), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:131)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elast
icsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16/0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2
015.03.16/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:881)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:769)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:458)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.readSegmentInfos(Lucene.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:122)
        ... 4 more
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,064][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] sending failed shard for [.marvel-2015.03.16][0],
 node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [FKpoioArTI-KxevMFlQKAQ], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGateway
RecoveryException[[.marvel-2015.03.16][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over]; nested: IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[.marve
l-2015.03.16][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no s
egments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16/
0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []]; ]]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,064][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] received shard failed for [.marvel-2015.03.16][0]
, node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [FKpoioArTI-KxevMFlQKAQ], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewa
yRecoveryException[[.marvel-2015.03.16][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over]; nested: IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[.marv
el-2015.03.16][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no
segments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16
/0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []]; ]]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,079][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] received shard failed for [.marvel-2015.03.16][0]
, node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [FKpoioArTI-KxevMFlQKAQ], reason [master [Trick Shot][4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg][E2pr
o-ESP-06][inet[/10.9.46.65:9300]] marked shard as initializing, but shard is marked as failed, resend shard failure]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,080][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] sending failed shard after recovery failure
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:157)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post ap
i), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:131)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elast
icsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.15/0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2
015.03.15/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:881)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:769)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:458)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.readSegmentInfos(Lucene.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:122)
        ... 4 more
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,080][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] sending failed shard for [.marvel-2015.03.15][0],
 node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [uFZ3KaB6Te2igqubyvkFHA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGateway
RecoveryException[[.marvel-2015.03.15][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over]; nested: IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[.marve
l-2015.03.15][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no s
egments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.15/
0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.15/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []]; ]]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,080][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] received shard failed for [.marvel-2015.03.15][0]
, node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [uFZ3KaB6Te2igqubyvkFHA], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewa
yRecoveryException[[.marvel-2015.03.15][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over]; nested: IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[.marv
el-2015.03.15][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no
segments* file found in store(least_used[rate_limited(default(mmapfs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.15
/0/index),niofs(/DATA/www/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.15/0/index)), type=MERGE, rate=20.0)]): files: []]; ]]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,094][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.15][0] received shard failed for [.marvel-2015.03.15][0]
, node[4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [uFZ3KaB6Te2igqubyvkFHA], reason [master [Trick Shot][4YS3jneRTn624zDl6C29Zg][E2pr
o-ESP-06][inet[/10.9.46.65:9300]] marked shard as initializing, but shard is marked as failed, resend shard failure]
[2015-04-04 15:18:01,096][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Trick Shot] [.marvel-2015.03.13][0] sending failed shard after recovery failure
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [.marvel-2015.03.13][0] failed to fetch index version after copying it over
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:157)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the logs to see what might be going on there? Are your log levels set to DEBUG or something?

Comment: There is something wrong with your marvel indexes, did you have a full disk? Feels like corruption. Can you start the node and remove the marvel indices? Maybe disable marvel for a while and see if the problem remains?

Comment: Guys, I've rectified issue. Seems like some files/folder got deleted at the time of moving from local system to server. I just restore once again all files from local system to server. Now, it's working fine.

Any way, thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart then please answer your own question and accept it!

Comment: Marvel's default sample interval is 10s for all indexes, including .marvel. I found a significant reduction in CPU load by setting the interval to 60s and removing the .marvel index from analysis. I suspect the interval is the key factor here.